# eclipse Failed to publish application! to azure

Tags: eclipse, deployment, azure

today i use eclipse and azure sdk for php
on azure i have create host service & storage when i Deploy Windows Azure PHP Project to Windows Azure has error

> Failed to publish application! Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd
>   hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

please help me
sory i'm not strong english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the JRE 1.6 instead of the last one (1.7), you should solve this problem.